# SFINAE to check the existence of operators (without decltype)

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae, c++98

I am trying to do an old project of my school, which deals with metaprogramming in C++98.
The part I'm struggling against is about SFINAE.

The subject says I'm supposed to check if `operator<<` works between a stream object and another object by the use of a struct like this :

```
template<typename Stream, typename Object>
struct IsPrintable;
```

It says I should write a weird line with "two null references", I guess it should look like this :

```
sizeof(*(static_cast<Stream *>(NULL)) << *(static_cast<Object *>(NULL)))
```

It works when the operator is supported, but doesn't compile when it isn't. 
I can't figure out where I fail, here is the file :

```
template<typename Flux, typename Object>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
struct IsPrintable
{
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no[2];

  template<size_t N>
  struct Test
  {
    typedef size_t type;
  };  

  template<typename U>
  static yes &isPrintable(U * = 0); 

  template<typename>
  static no &isPrintable(...);

  static const bool value = sizeof(isPrintable<Test<sizeof(*(static_cast<Flux *>(NULL)) << *(static_cast<Object *>(NULL)))> >(0)) == sizeof(yes);

};
```

The subject says explicitly to use a class taking a size_t as a parameter, and that the isPrintable method should take a NULL pointer to this class instance. Plus, the ugly expressions with static_cast should be used for a type definition, I tried to typedef it but the compiler screamed at me.

I don't get everything since I'm very new to this, I know there is some way to simplify that with the `decltype` operator, but the aim of the project is to do it in C++98, and it could be useful if I find some code of that type later on.

Comment: Hint: You need to put the `static_cast` line into a place where it will cause substitution failure, not a compilation error.

Comment: SFINAE being taught at school? I don't even.

Comment: This actually depends on [expression SFINAE](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html), which is only...kind of...part of C++98.

Comment: @Cicada - don't get surprised, it is "an old project" :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all ! So I misplaced this line, it's quite hard to understand.. but I will tryhard ! @SChepurin Yeah it's 2 years old, they still give it to students AFAIK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename Flux, typename Object>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
struct IsPrintable
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <std::size_t N>
    struct SFINAE {};

    template <typename F, typename O>
    static yes& isPrintable(SFINAE<sizeof( *static_cast<F*>(NULL) << *static_cast<O*>(NULL) )>* = 0); 

    template <typename F, typename O>
    static no& isPrintable(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(isPrintable<Flux, Object>(NULL)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80e7884f8e58cdbc)

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename Flux, typename Object>
struct IsPrintable
{
private:
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <size_t N> struct Test
    {
        typedef size_t type;
    };

    template <typename U>
    static yes& isPrintable(Test<sizeof(*(static_cast<Flux*>(NULL)) << *(static_cast<U*>(NULL)))>* = 0);

    template <typename> static no& isPrintable(...);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(isPrintable<Object>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Ligs7d)